# Formatting text in a .txt File

Tags: java, file, text

I have to create a little program for a text file like this:

```
hello_this_is_a_test_Example_
 this line has to go up because it has a space at the beginning
 this one too
this is the next line because there's no space at the start
 this one has to connect with the first line
```

I hope you understand.

So at the end, it should save the formatted text in a file like this:

```
hello_this_is_a_test_Example_ this line has to go up because it has a space at the beginning this one too
this is the next line because there's no space at the start this one has to connect with te upper again
```

Basically, if the line has a space character at the start of each string, it has to connect with the top line. I already have the GUI to select both files just need the algorithms. Thank you in advance :D

I have this at the moment but it puts everything in one line. It's not right:

```
public class Engine {

    public void Process(String fileIn,String fileOut) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("[Info]--> Processign");
        System.out.println("[Info]--> FileIn = " + fileIn);
        System.out.println("[Info]--> FileOut = " + fileOut);
        FileWriter Writer = new FileWriter(fileOut);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileIn));
        String line;
        String modified;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
            Writer.write(line);
         if(line.startsWith(" ")){
            modified = line.replaceAll("\n ", " ");
            Writer.write(modified);
         }
        } 
        br.close();
        Writer.close();}    
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far besides writing a super enterprisey GUI for this? Try out something on your own and come back if you still run into errors or if you don't understand something. SO is not a "do my homework plox" place.

Comment: For reading a text file line by line, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432970/import-textfile-and-read-line-by-line-in-java). The algorithm of looking to see if the line starts with a space etc. is very simple, you should be able to find that out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String modified = yourString.replaceAll("\n ", " ");
```

Try something like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in Files.ReadAllLines(@"c:\myfile.txt"))
{
    builder.append(line);
}
String modified = builder.toString().replaceAll("\n ", " ");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(@"c:\myfile.txt");
fw.write(modified);
fw.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but its not working i have this at the moment ::

Comment: You need to run this on a sring containing the entire file.

Comment: thanks but dont get this part : foreach (string line in Files.ReadAllLines(@"c:\myfile.txt"))
{
    builder.append(line);
}

Comment: You read the file in a list of strings and append each line to the builder so you produce a string out of the entire file.

Comment: you will need to reference the java.nio.file.Files