# Complete noob, Android app help (array)

Tags: java, android, arrays

Im really sorry if I start to annoy anyone, I have spent weeks trying to do this and I need to get my app (quiz) done and I just cannot seem to understand how to achieve this (my hats off to all programmers). So I’m going to try and sort it out bit by bit. Let me start by giving you an overview of what I am trying to do.

Page/activity 1 = 4 buttons to various quiz catagories, I just want one to work right now.

Page 2 = I want a question and 4 possible answers (shuffled), and a next button, then will scroll to the next question.

Last page I would like all correct answers added up and either a 8/10 scenario, or if possible and time and ability permits a picture of trophy and colour defined by score.

Now so far I have got my layouts done I think, drag and drop I can do.

I have spent this last week trying to get a database of questions and answers to work but I couldnt so I have settled on doing arrays.

First question is this this is what my arrays looks like, and I have set it up in its own class, is this workable or stupid?

```
public class QuestionSets {

String mathsQuestions[]= {
        "What is 10 * 4 =?",
        " How many sides does a cube have?", 
        "What is Pi equal to, to 2 decimal places?", 
        "What is 595 172 correct to the nearest thousand?", 
        "What is 2.5 * 100?", 
        "What is 90 out of 200 as a percentage?", 
        "What is y if y=5x+5 if x is 5?", 
        "What is 66 + 108?", 
        "What is 1 + 0.6?, What is 10 - 8=?"};

String correctAnswers[]= 
    {"40", "6", "3.14", "595 000", "250", "45%", "30", "174", "1.6", "2"};

String option1 [] = 
    {"50", "4", "4.13", "596 000", "25", "40%", "40", "170", "0.7", "4"};

String option2 [] = 
    {"45", "7", "5,14", "600 000", "200", "50%", "25", "178", "7", "80"};

String option3 [] = 
    {"54", "3", "2.13", "500 000", "2000", "90%", "20", "180", "6", "18"};

// ...
```

The correct and incorrect answers are in line with the questions.

I saw someone do array lists things which i have put in the questions class, is this even right either? i really have no idea, but this is what i have done there.

```
// ...

ArrayList<Integer> mthsQuestions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayList<Integer> crtAns = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

ArrayList<Integer> optn1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

ArrayList<Integer> optn2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayList<Integer> optn3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

}
```

Also why are they integers, shouldnt they be strings?

Thanks

Comment: if you want the user to enter something like `40%` or `1.6` then `Integer` is indeed wrong and you should use `String`

Comment: Its not something the user will enter, im hoping to attach them to radio buttons to choose an answeer, i saw some code for someone doing something similar and they used integers and i wondered whether the values are stored as numbers? the starting at 0 thing 0-9 for 10 array elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'right, it's wrong. You should use `ArrayList<String>`. You can fill it at initialization:

```
ArrayList<String> optn3 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(option3));
```

But, from an engineering point of view, it would be better to have the questions and the answers in a separate text file which your program would read. That way you can change the questions or add new ones without the need to recompile the program.

Comment: I was told text files would be better, but i know nothing about them and i have to do this app today, it only needs to do something, doesnt have to be good lol.

Thanks for the suggestion, it looks good and i think i understand it.

Comment: For text files, you can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714385/read-text-file-in-java)